# I want to run a script when known bluetooth device connects/disconnects to WinXP

Tags: windows, bluetooth

I have a laptop on my desk at work. I have screensaver timer enabled, so if I'm not using the computer for ten minutes, it will start the screensaver. I also have "On resume, password protect" option checked. This is useful and I want it to be so. However, sometimes I just sit at my cubicle and read some documents without touching the computer. During that time I want my computer to know that I'm there and that there is no need to start the screensaver.

I have a mobile phone that is bluetooth paired with the laptop for synchronizing calendars. Is there some way for a script or a program to know that any (or specified) paired device is connected? While typing this out I thought that there might be some registry entries for this. Does anyone have any thoughts on this?

-Rope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I severely doubt that there is built-in capability for this. An operating system is not for every conceivable use case of a computer out there, it exists to provide the building blocks to build such applications.

Anyway, I suspect you can write a simple program which looks for your paired device and then prevents the screensaver from running (for which there is an API).

Comment: I guess you're right. I made a quick registry diff and only direct change related to bluetooth connections was mobile phone manufacturer specific. Value that changes has a predictable behavior so I guess I can build something on that. Thanks. I'm going to give others a chance, but will accept your answer later, if nothing earth shattering comes up.

Comment: @rope: I'd leave the registry out of it and instead build an application to do what it should do: Watch for Bluetooth devices appearing/disappearing. Trying to rely on something un(der)?documented is probably not the best way to go.

Comment: As usual my quest has led me to deepest of depths. I just saw the Amulet of Yendor, but passed it by and continued deeper. :) It appears that "Watch for Bluetooth devices appearing/disappearing" part cannot be made generic because Bluetooth device discovery is device manufacturer specific. Maybe I just make it to work with Broadcom Bluetooth stack, which my laptop uses and forget the others for now.